# How to remove file from git repository but only up to a certain point in history?

Tags: git, repository, git-clone, git-filter-branch

I know how to use filter-branch to completely leave a file out of the repository history. What happened is that I had slightly sensitive information in a file some commits ago, but I have removed it and I want to keep the file from that safe commit onwards.

Can I do it? Or will I have to to do some cloning tricks?

Comment: I guess you have to run a `git filter-branch` with tree filter. Though, I have no time to give you better answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think [BFG Repo-Cleaner](https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner) is exactly what you're looking for.

You can use it to *replace* or *remove* sensitive information contained in the working tree (like for example a password) throughout the history of the repository. Here's an example from their [documentation](https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/#usage):

```
bfg --replace-text passwords.txt /path/to/repository
```

The `passwords.txt` file would then contain a series of strings to match together with what value they should be replaced with. For example:

```
password             # Replaces the string 'password' with '***REMOVED***' (default)
password==>DELETED   # Replaces the string 'password' with 'DELETED'
password==>          # Replaces the string 'password' with an empty string
regex:password.+==>  # Replaces using a regular expression with an empty string
```

As with `git-filter-branch`, this is a [rewrite history](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History) operation, so the usual disclaimer applies.